Is it possible to update ui elements with asynchronous functions in .net winforms?
I got the idea to make a lattice from windows and animate their position according to a sine wave that takes their x and y positions and the current time to make a sort of wavy effect just for fun, and I tried using async functions to update the positions of the windows but it stalled on the task, while running it synchronously with the invoke method of the Form class it worked just fine. I'm extremely new to winforms as I learned it just yesterday to make the thing I thought of and I don't exactly know what's supported and what's not
practically, I tried to make an async function, that takes as an argument an array of forms, returns void, and starts up a task with a for loop for every form in the array, and using await Task.whenall(tasks) to make sure everything stays on phase. unfortunately the tasks never executed, but running it synchronously worked just fine
static int screenWidth;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int sizeX = 190, sizeY = 190;
    int count = 40;

    screenWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
    Form[] forms = CreateWindows(count, sizeX, sizeY);
    Point[] origins = new Point[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < forms.Length; i++)
    {
        forms[i].Show();
        forms[i].Location = new Point((((sizeX * i) % screenWidth)/sizeX) * sizeX, ((sizeX * (i)) / screenWidth (sizeY+10));
        origins[i] = forms[i].Location;
        }

        while (true)
        {
            MoveWindows(forms, origins);
        }
    }

this is the main function I used for creating the window array, create windows just creates the windows
now that I think about it I should have made it also return the origin array instead of creating everything then moving it to the correct position. that's not the point though
static void MoveWindows(Form[] forms, Point[] origins)
{

    long time = System.DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    for (int i = 0; i < forms.Length; i++)
    {
        int currentIndex = i;
        forms[currentIndex].Invoke((Action)(() => {
            int thing = (int)(Math.Sin((origins[currentIndex].X + origins[currentIndex].Y) / 170.0 + (double)time / 2000000) * 30);
            int newX = origins[currentIndex].X + thing;
            int newY = origins[currentIndex].Y + thing;
            forms[currentIndex].Location = new Point(newX, newY);
        }));
    }
}

this is the code I'm currently using, sorry for not commenting I just didn't expect I'd need to share it. it works well, only problem is that it starts lagging as the number of windows increases, because it's single threaded for now
what I tried to do is inside of MoveWindows, instead of invoking every change one after the other, start a task for each window to change its position then Task.WhenAll to make sure the windows remain in sync and that there's no sudden jumps. I'll make a snippet of something like that I deleted my last attempt. assume that main is an async function
static async Task MoveWindowsAsync(Form[] forms, Point[] origins)
{
    long time = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    Task[] tasks = new Task[forms.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < forms.Length; i++) {
        int currentIndex = i;
        tasks[i] = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            int thing = (int)(Math.Sin((origins[currentIndex].X + origins[currentIndex].Y) / 170.0 + (double)time / 2000000) * 30);
            int newX = origins[currentIndex].X + thing;
            int newY = origins[currentIndex].Y + thing;
            forms[currentIndex].Location = new Point(newX, newY);
        });
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}


If you have written some code for this task, then post that code, don't describe it or talk about what it should do -- I tried to make an async function, that takes as an argument an array of forms: don't. If you need to generate data based on some values, then pass those values to async methods, not instances of Forms. Then call back to the UI Thread for the updates. If you are plotting / drawing something, this needs to happen in the UI Thread, using the provided methods / events (OnPaint() / OnPaintBackGround() / Paint event) or use specialized Controls. Painting is synchronous

You definitely need to edit your post and include the code you have that's not working, we have no chance of guessing what's wrong.

I was mostly asking for theory, as in "does winforms support x and y" instead of "why no work"

You cannot create, access, or update any UI element from a non-UI thread. You can invoke code back to the UI thread, but that can lead to all sorts of race conditions in the cases where the tasks complete out of order.

@Enigmativity so what I was trying to do is impossible? that's a shame if so, I thought of expanding on it but I guess it's more size-limited than I thought
